# *** multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: java, linux, makefile

I am trying to make a makefile for compiling a single java class on linux. I made a makefile for it, as follows:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
CLASSES = \
    des.java \
default: classes
classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

This gives me the error Makefile:9: *** multiple target patterns. Stop.
Where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray line-continuation marker on the `des.java \` line.

This is causing make to assign the value `des.java default: classes` to the `CLASSES` variable.

When make then expands that on the `classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)` line it sees multiple colons and gets confused.

Comment: Thanks very much! Did not notice that. That error is fixed. Now I am getting "No rule to make target `des.class', needed by `classes'. I am new to makefiles for java, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a `des.java` file in your current directory? If you do that should be working.